# primefaces5 jsf2 multiple upload e scan the elements

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, multi-upload

Hi to all i have a problem with an upload of more files in PrimeFaces/Jsf2

I see http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/multiple.xhtml

When the method intercept the event associated i set

UploadedFile fileUpload = event.getFile();

and i want to scan every file uploaded with the implementation of List

```
    InputStream input;
    input = event.getFile().getInputstream();
    pojo.setFileInputStream(input);
    input.close();
    fileTableList.add(pojo);
```

But the great problem is that this list contain only one file uploaded.
How can i take every file uploaded from UploadedFile event?

What's wrong?
Thank you for the answers

Comment: You will need to store `InputStream` or `byte[]` or even `UploadedFile` depending upon the need extracted from files being uploaded into a collection or an array i.e. inside `fileUploadListener`.

Comment: I think so but every i-element of byte array is an UploadedFile?

Comment: My problem is that i control the name of every FileUploaded with the previous file so i want a list of the names of every file.

Comment: The type of the collection depends upon the requirement. It could be `InputStream`, `byte[]` or even `UploadedFile` or something else. The file name can be obtained by using `uploadedFile.getFileName()`. So, you will need to decide based on the requirement which type of information is to be stored into a collection. You may only need `byte[]` and the file name, `InputStream` and the file name or the entire `UploadedFile` object...

Comment: Yes the file name  can be obtained by using uploadedFile.getFileName(), but how i capture every fileName for stored them in a List? This method show with the recursion all names contemporaly.

Answer (score 0):

> But the great problem is that this list contain only one file
>   uploaded. How can I take every file uploaded from `UploadedFile`
>   event?

This cannot be reproduced with a minimal example with least possible dependencies / resources unless you explicitly state with a minimum reproducible example.

---

Create a utility class like the following (the class is fully dependent upon the requirement).

```
public class FileUtil implements Serializable {

    private InputStream inputStream; // One can also use byte[] or something else.
    private String fileName;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FileUtil() {}

    // Overloaded constructor(s) + getters + setters + hashcode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

The managed bean receiving multiple files :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private List<FileUtil> fileList;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
        UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
        FileUtil fileUtil = new FileUtil();
        fileUtil.setInputStream(file.getInputstream());
        fileUtil.setFileName(file.getFileName());
        fileList.add(fileUtil);
    }


    // Bound to a <p:commandButton>.

    public void action() {
        for (FileUtil fileUtil : fileList) {
            System.out.println(fileUtil.getFileName());
        }

        // Use the list of files here and clear the list afterwards, if needed.
        fileList.clear();
    }
}
```

The XHTML file holding only a `<p:fileUpload>` and a `<p:commandButton>` just for the sake of demonstration.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:fileUpload id="fileUpload"
                  mode="advanced"
                  fileLimit="5"
                  multiple="true"
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                  sequential="true"
                  process="@this"
                  fileUploadListener="#{testBean.fileUploadListener}">
    </p:fileUpload>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                     process="@this"
                     update="fileUpload"
                     actionListener="#{testBean.action}"/>
</h:form>
```

---

If you need `byte[]` in place of `InputStream`, then just change `private InputStream inputStream;` in the `FileUtil` class to `byte[]` and then use

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedFile.getInputstream());
```

to extract a byte array from `InputStream` (where `IOUtils` is from `org.apache.commons.io`. You can also do it manually just by writing a few lines of code).

You can also construct a `List<UploadedFile>` without creating an additional class like `FileUtil` as in this example but doing so would mandate a PrimeFaces dependency on the service layer (which should not happen), if you happened to use that layer in your application, since `UploadedFile` is a PrimeFaces artifact. After all it fully depends upon the requirement.

Comment: thank Tiny, the problem is that i can't do control operation on every fileName because there is one only istance that contain all fileNames; i also thinked to byte[] but my application stay on the cloud system and i can't write on physical memory

Comment: I do not get term, "*Control operation*".

Comment: Sequential control for the names of the files.. i want to iterate a list of name files. The list of FileUtil not iterates in each file name

Comment: I'm not know that how explain. it repeates the istructions for every file uploaded. If i launch  System.out.println(fileUtil.getFileName()) after the upload of 4 files, the output is:  element1  ->  element1  element2 -> element1 element2 element3 -> element1 element2 element3 element4;  if i launch a system out of the size of the list the output is:  1-> 2 -> 3 -> 4. It use (i think) a recursion or similar.